# Unable to apply a plugin to CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So, I use CKEDITOR in my application. I really like it, except one nasty thing - the toolbar disappears totally when I have some huge text and have to scroll down. So, when I scroll back there is no toolbar at all. I found a [plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/fixed)
which is supposed to solve this problem. So, this is what I did - I added this plugin to my application like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/plugins/fixed/plugin.js"></script>
```

The script is loaded ok - I see it in the console. Then in the application itself I do this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'fixed'
};
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( document.getElementById("code") , {
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
  shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
  autoParagraph: false,
  height: height                                
});
```

But this plugin does not help - when I scroll down, he toolbar still disappears. So, I need some help. PS. I'm using CKEDITOR 4.

Comment: I checked even the most recent version of CKEDITOR and see the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to manually add the js file itself, you just need to define the configuration properly.

Test this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( document.getElementById("code") , {
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
  shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
  autoParagraph: false,
  height: height ,
  extraPlugins : 'fixed'                              
});
```